# Android WifiP2pManager DialogListener Class Not Found Exception

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am developing an app based on Android Wi-Fi Direct. I want to connect devices without foreground dialog permission. Codes in the link below work properly for Galaxy Note 4 (Android 6.0.1) but when I tried it on LG G3 (Android 5.0) it throws ClassNotFoundException at code below.

dialogInterface = Class.forName("android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager$DialogListener");

https://github.com/octoblu/alljoyn/blob/master/alljoyn/alljoyn_java/helper/org/alljoyn/bus/p2p/WifiDirectAutoAccept.java

Answer (score 1):

There might not be a whole lot you can do in this case.

DialogListener is marked as @hide in WifiP2pManager, and there is no guarantee that this interface will exist across all versions of Android. Based on the [stock 6.0.1 source code](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.java), I don't even see evidence that this interface exists, so I'm surprised this even works on the Note (unless Samsung did some customization). I do see this interface in [4.1.2](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.java/?v=source), though.

To troubleshoot issues with reflection, I recommend using a debugger to examine the object (WifiP2pManager) that is giving you trouble.